# Checkout - Accept email id in login.phtml step of one page magento checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, php, checkout

During the checkout process, in billing.phtml the following submit code accepts the various inputs given by the user

```
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?>" class="button" onclick="billing.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
    <span class="please-wait" id="billing-please-wait" style="display:none;">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
    </span>
```

It specifically looks like the `onclick="billing.save()"` causes the entries to be processed.

How do i modify the above to accept `email id` in the previous `login.phtml` step of the one page checkout process ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? As the previous step should allow users to login via the email address by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you try to achieve.

But when you look into the source you see different `<form>` for the different steps. if you want to add a field which should be submitted with the `billing.save()` you either put it into the `#co-billing-form` or you change the JS code which submits all the data.

Comment: @fabein have sort of figured it out now ...